# Force Lang in Prestashopp

Tags: php, html, forms, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Hi im developing a litle addon to prestashop, its done and works but in the productive server the label for a botton change the langueage, the botton must say "Enviar", but when i test the addon on my phone the botton change to "Submit".

How can i force the text inside de botton ?

i used this code to make the botton

```
<div>
    <input style=" border: none; border-radius:0; background-color: #9dc233;" value="Enviar" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="tracking-btn"></input>
</div>
```

This is how looks in the browser

[image]

this is how looks in the phone browser

[image]

Comment: try this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_translate.asp#:~:text=The%20translate%20attribute%20specifies%20whether,%22no%22%3A%20ice%20cream.

Comment: Try removing the cache from the admin panel and browser cache.